# Laravel UUIDs and relationships

Tags: laravel, uuid

I'm working on an API using UUID. I am leveraging `michaeldyrynda/laravel-model-uuid` and `michaeldyrynda/laravel-efficient-uuid` to make it as efficient as possible.

The doc for laravel-model-uuid suggest to not use the UUID as the primary key of the models. Does it mean that for all my models using UUIDs I will have an auto-increment integer PK (e.g. id) and a uuid columns?

Does it means that all relationships are meant to use regular IDs?

So for example, say I have an endpoint to store a comment on an article, the body of the call might include the article uuid, and before creating the comment, I will have to find the article by uuid to set the right article_id on the new comment.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, It is strongly recommended **NOT** to use UUID as the primary key

Since how the PK indexing in MySQL won't favor anything from using UUID, it mostly only hurts the performance since the random UUID will make the data insertion slower (because it needs to look for where to put the UUID in the "lookup table")

The performance won't be felt at the beginning of your project, but when your data is starting to grow, you will feel the impact on performance when you insert a new record.

Back to your question,

> The doc for laravel-model-uuid suggest to not use the UUID as the primary key of the models. Does it mean that for all my models using UUIDs I will have an auto-increment integer PK (e.g. id) and a uuid columns?
>
> Does it means that all relationships are meant to use regular IDs?

The answer is yes, if this what you wanted, you can use a normal auto increment ID as your internal reference (e.g. foreign key on the other table), and when your app want to show the ID you can show the UUID as your app resource ID.

So basically the job for UUID is just for public ID, all internal reference will use the good old AI ID.

read more on: https://www.percona.com/blog/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/

Comment: just curious, what if i'm using postgresql?

Comment: @YusufGiovanno UUID might still impact multiple aspects of Postgresql, e.g you cannot perform MAX/MIN operations on it.

Comment: @MrK ahh right, thanks for the insight mate